# PostgreSQL : SQL Request with a Group By and a Percentage on two differents tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by, percentage

I'm currently blocked on an complex request (with a join):

I have this table "DATA":

```
order | product
----------------
  1   |  A 
  1   |  B  
  2   |  A  
  2   |  D   
  3   |  A  
  3   |  C
  4   |  A  
  4   |  B
  5   |  Y  
  5   |  Z
  6   |  W  
  6   |  A
  7   |  A
```

And this table "DICO":

```
    order | couple | first | second
    -------------------------------
      1   |  A-B   |   A   |   B
      2   |  A-D   |   A   |   D
      3   |  A-C   |   A   |   C
      4   |  A-B   |   A   |   B
      5   |  Y-Z   |   Y   |   Z
      6   |  W-A   |   W   |   A
```

I would like to obtain, on one line :

```
order | count | total1stElem | %1stElem | total2ndElem | %2ndElem
------------------------------------------------------------------
A-B   |  2    |       6      |    33%   |     2        |    100%       
A-D   |  1    |       6      |    16%   |     1        |    100%      
A-C   |  1    |       6      |    16%   |     1        |    100%         
Y-Z   |  1    |       1      |    100%  |     1        |    100%     
W-A   |  1    |       1      |    100%  |     6        |    16%
```

Information:

```
Fields: (On the 1st Line example)
  total1stElem : count ALL('A') in table Data (all occurrences of A in Data) 
  total2ndElem : count ALL('B') in table Data (all occurrences of B in Data)
  Count : count the number of 'A-B' occurence in table Dico
  %1stElem = ( Count / total1stElem ) * 100
  %1ndElem = ( Count / total2ndElem ) * 100
```

I'm based on this request:

```
select couple, count(*),
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by first) as total,
       (count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over (partition by first) ) as ratio
from dico1
group by couple, first ORDER BY ratio DESC;
```

And I want to do something like :

```
select couple, count(*) as COUNT,
       count(*) over (partition by product #FROM DATA WHERE product = first#) as total1stElem,
       (count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over (partition by product #FROM DATA WHERE product = first#) as %1stElem
       count(*) over (partition by product #FROM DATA WHERE product = second#) as total2ndElem,
       (count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over (partition by product #FROM DATA WHERE product = second#) as %2ndElem
from dico1
group by couple, first ORDER BY COUNT DESC;
```

I'm totally blocked on the jointure part of my request. Somebody can help me ? I've been helped for this kind or request on Oracle, but unfortunately it's impossible to adapt UNPIVOT and PIVOT function in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Can you explain how the values of `total1stElem`, `total2ndElem` are computed?

Comment: Its really unclear. please add the query you tried and explain more

Comment: Thanks for recommandation, I do my best to explain better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create CTEs that aggregate each table and count the occurrences you listed, and join `dico`'s aggregation on `data`'s aggregation twice, once for `first` and once for `second`:

```
WITH data_count AS (
    SELECT   product, COUNT(*) AS product_count
    FROM     data
    GROUP BY product
),
dico_count AS (
    SELECT   couple, first, second, COUNT(*) AS dico_count
    FROM     dico
    GROUP BY couple, first, second
)
SELECT   couple,
         dico_count,
         data1.product_count AS total1stElem,
         TRUNC(dico_count * 100.0 / data1.product_count) AS percent1stElem,
         data2.product_count AS total2ndElem,
         TRUNC(dico_count * 100.0 / data2.product_count) AS percent2ndElem
FROM     dico_count dico
JOIN     data_count data1 ON dico.first = data1.product
JOIN     data_count data2 ON dico.second = data2.product
ORDER BY 1
```